# Line equation tangent to convex level curve

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

Suppose we are given a differentiable function $f(x,y)$ such that $\forall$ $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $f = t$ yields strictly convex level curves. If we are given a line equation $y = mx + c$ such that it always intersects two points of a level curve or is tangent to it or does not intersect at all, will it mean that a level curve tangent to $y = mx + c$ always exists (given the line cuts at least one level curve)?

I am not sure if this holds, but intuitively it feels like that, although I don't have a solid intuition to solve this. Using the Mean Value Theorem, one can say that a tangent with slope $m$ exists that will intersect a given level curve. But I can't extend this to prove that the line $y = mx + c$ itself will be tangent to some level curve.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand you but I would assume that quasi-linear preferences with a corner solution are a counterexample.

Comment: @JesperHybel It doesn't work I suppose. Because the budget line has to intersect the curves $U=c$ either at two points, or at a point of tangency, or nowhere.

Comment: 1. You should define what precisely you mean by tangency.

Comment: 2. Are you familiar with the [hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem)? You can apply it here directly.

Comment: @Giskard (1) If $U(x,y) = c$ touches a line $y = rx + s$ at exactly one point where $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = r$, then it's a point of tangency. (2) No.

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample:
$$
f(x,y)= \ln ((x-5)(y-5))
$$
and the line is
$$
x+y=1.
$$
All level curves of $f$ will stay above the point (5,5), not touching the line at all.
$f$ is differentiable and has full range (takes all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ values) as specified.

Comment: What about $(x,y) = (0.5,0.5)$ and $f = 2\ln(4.5)$? I think an easier counter would be $\frac{1}{x} = yc$ and line equation $x+y=0$. But the goal of the question is not to turn it into choosing the right range where the function exists and counter it. So reconsider the problem:  the line equation lies between the ICs with the minimum and the maximum utilities (if max and min exist), otherwise, the line equation cuts at least one level curve.

Comment: If you wish to reconsider the problem make a *final* edit; do not invent new details later on. It is on the OP to include all assumptions in their question.

Comment: I think the current version is final. As I write these questions myself, I tend to miss out certain edge cases. But here's what I can do then -- I will create a new post from now on rather than modifying it.